# F# ConsoleKeyInfo type mismatch

Tags: f#

I have Console.ReadKey() statement in my program to pause execution

```
System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

but VS code shows me an error:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'ConsoleKeyInfo -> int'    
but given a
    'ConsoleKeyInfo -> unit'    
The type 'int' does not match the type 'unit'
```

How do I fix it ?

Comment: I suspect something else is causing this. Is this part of a larger expression?

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is expecting an int as the last value.  If System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore is the last line in your function, then it is returning unit.  I suspect the answer you wish to return is on the previous line.  Use "let" to capture that value, do the ReadKey() on the next line, then put your let value on the last line to return it.  For instance:

```
let foo : int= 
    let sum = 1 + 1
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    sum
```

Comment: It is probably the last line in the program. As such it needs to return an exit code of `0` to indicate success or something else to indicate an error.